# There is no registered service of type

Tags: blazor

I am trying to make a new version of AuthenticationStateProvider so that I can use the data already in my db. I called it ServerAuthenticationStateProvider:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BadgerWatchWeb.Services
{
    public class ServerAuthenticationStateProvider :    AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    string UserId;
    string Password;
    bool IsAuthenticated = false;

    public void LoadUser(string _UserId, string _Password)
    {
        UserId = _UserId;
        Password = _Password;
    }

    public async Task LoadUserData()
    {
        var securityService = new SharedServiceLogic.Security();
        try
        {
            var passwordCheck = await securityService.ValidatePassword(UserId, Password);
            IsAuthenticated = passwordCheck == true ? true : false;
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var userService = new UserService();

        var identity = IsAuthenticated
            ? new ClaimsIdentity(await userService.GetClaims(UserId))
            : new ClaimsIdentity();

        var result = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        return result;
    }

}
```

}

My configure services looks like:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
    }
```

I then inject `@inject ServerAuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider` into my razor view file.

When I run the code I get `InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'AuthenticationStateProvider' on type 'BadgerWatchWeb.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type 'BadgerWatchWeb.Services.ServerAuthenticationStateProvider'.`

Comment: For me, the problem was that I didn't register the service in Startup.cs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should replace

```
@inject ServerAuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
```

with

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
```

because that is how you registered it.

Answer (score 6):

Note:
When you add a service to the DI container, the left-side parameter should be an interface ( or an abstract class), whereas the right-side parameter should be the concrete class, like the following:

```
services.AddScoped<IJSRuntime, RemoteJSRuntime>();
```

And you can inject the type IJSRuntime into your component like this:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
```

IJSRuntime is the type to inject, JSRuntime is the name of the property which will contain the injected instance

Why do you call your class **ServerAuthenticationStateProvider**
This is the very same name of the AuthenticationStateProvider added to your DI container by the Blazor framework:

*ComponentServiceCollectionExtensions.AddServerSideBlazor method:*

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```

Please, modify your app according to the comments above, run your app, and come to report of errors,if any...

**Important**

- Make sure you understand the role and functionality of the AuthenticationStateProvider type, how it is populated with the authentication state data, when, and by whom. You should have derived your custom AuthenticationStateProvider from the 
  ServerAuthenticationStateProvider type defined by Blazor, as this type has a method which is called by the CircuitHost to set the authentication state...
- I did not peruse the code in your custom implementation of  AuthenticationStateProvider, but I'd say that it has to contain logic that only pertains to authentication state, and nothing else (separation of  concerns). And, yes, use it only if is necessary.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I spent time for not recognizing this important point when using interface for @inject statement

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't work because i had a **mutated vowel** in my **Database Name**:
My db name was "Bücher.dbo" and the "**ü**" wasn't accepted.

I changed the name to "Books.dbo" and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, since I was using MudBlazor, I needed to add `MudServices`. Like this:

In file Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddMudServices(); //This one was missing
```